# What is the reason that crash has occurred in Splunk? (splunk crash)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash, splunk

I use Splunk error reporting system in android.

today suddenly encountered the following crash report.
I don't know why this crash occurred.

please let me know if you know reason of this crash

thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.splunk.mint.RemoteSettings.com.splunk.mint.RemoteSettingsData convertJsonToRemoteSettings(java.lang.String)(SourceFile:38)
    at com.splunk.mint.ActionEvent.void send(android.content.Context,com.splunk.mint.NetSender,boolean)(SourceFile:111)
    at com.splunk.mint.Mint$2.void run()(SourceFile:183)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

please tell me if you are encountered same problem.

Comment: did you find the solution.I have same issue from yesterday.Could you please let me know which mint SDK version you are using?I was using mint 4.0.I have issue only on Lollipop/Kitkat version devices.Please help me out if you got any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We got the issue with Mint 4.3.0, answer from Splunk Support :

> General Support, Sep 10, 12:32: Hi - Thank you for reaching out and
>   providing detailed information. We're sorry for the impact of this
>   issue. The issue is now resolved. If you continue to see issues,
>   please let us know.

Hopefully they will release a fix to protect client against that